# Single login for two different web applications

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication

I have two different web applications built in Angular frontend and NodeJS backend. Both applications have login functionality separately.

But if I login one application I should also able to use another application without logging in.

How should I handle this in proper way. Please suggest

Comment: What you're looking for is called [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) (Single sign-on).

Comment: Are your two web applications on different domains?

Comment: @phatfingers Yes two different domains

Comment: I concur with @TotallyNewb in that you're describing a need for SSO.  What solution you use often depends on whether your customers already have accounts in some centrally managed system.  Essentially, you're telling your servers to send new requestors to a 3rd server that logs the users in and sends them back with a token you validate before allowing them in.  When valid, you give them a cookie just like you probably do today when they've authenticated.